# Diferencias regionales en la pronunciación de la letra "c" (aspiración)

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación, hispanoamérica, colombia, letras

He notado que en algunos lados he escuchado a la gente pronunciar palabras como "Acá" con la letra "C" aspirada como en la palabra "Car" en inglés.

¿Entonces en cuáles países o regiones del mundo existe este fenómeno? ¿Y hay reglas que rijan la selección de una "C" aspirada (supongo que lo mismo cabe decir de la letra 'Q') en vez de un "C" normal como en la parte final de la palabra "Duck" en inglés?

¿O tal vez puede que se trate de alguna afectación?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El sonido de /k/ en español (que es el de la *c* en *casa*, el de *qu* en *queso* y el de *k* en *kilogramo*) es no aspirado, como regla general, al igual que el sonido de /t/ y /p/, las otras dos consonantes oclusivas sordas del idioma.

No especificaste en qué lugares has escuchado a la gente pronunciar esta /k/ como aspirada, pero por el tag `colombia` deduzco que habrá sido en Colombia. No encuentro ninguna referencia a que en un dialecto colombiano se pronuncie la /k/ con aspiración.

Hay al menos un dialecto español, [el del Yucatán (en México)](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/bitstream/handle/1840.2/2586/Michnowicz%20%26%20Carpenter%202013%20-%20ptk%20in%20Yucatan%20Spanish.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), donde se ha observado una tendencia a aspirar las oclusivas sordas /p t k/, por influencia del idioma maya yucatec de la región.

También existe un fenómeno muy conocido y estudiado de pre- y post-aspiración de las oclusivas sordas [en el español de Andalucía](https://www.journal-labphon.org/articles/10.5334/labphon.2/), pero eso es sólo un subproducto de la aspiración de la /s/ en final de sílaba y por lo tanto no se aplica a lo que estás relatando.

Es posible que hayas escuchado aspirar consonantes a personas que quieren darle énfasis a ciertas palabras, o que hayan crecido hablando algún otro idioma (inglés o algún idioma nativo americano) donde se aspiren las consonantes, pero es difícil saberlo sin más información detallada sobre quiénes son y dónde viven.

Comment: Sí lo he visto en Colombia, en Medellín, en particular la forma de hablar de las chicas allí. No sé si los hombres hablan de la misma manera, pero a mí, me parece muy obvio cuando hablan las chicas que estan pronunciando el sonido /k/ con aspiración. Suena casi como angloparlantes cuando dicen acá, por qué, calor, etc.

Comment: Entonces puede ser que sea una afectación, una moda. No es algo que haya sido reconocido o estudiado (por ahora).

Comment: Quizá lo veo más como argot que como parte de un dialecto... en Paisa (El dialecto que concierne a la región de Antioquia, el viejo Caldas y el norte del Valle del Cauca), sin bien no soy lingüista, tampoco reconozco el sonido que mencionas. Incluso, probando con las palabras que sugieres en inglés en el sitio https://tophonetics.com/ no se nota la diferencia...

Comment: Es muy poco probable que algo así quede registrado. Tendría que mantenerse en el tiempo y ser muy notorio, y después además un equipo de lingüistas tendría que toparse con el tema y decidir investigarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Soy de Uruguay y me cuesta identificar de dónde es algún hispanoparlante del norte de América del Sur o de América Central o el Caribe.
Yo también he notado en TV esas c o k pronunciadas con mucho aire y siempre era gente de Colombia. Parece una c de inglés o alemán.